# How to add gui elements to methods and call them?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, methods

This works as intended, but I was just wondering how to clean it up so that I can put each of the three panels (inputPanel, buttonPanel, and outputPanel) into their own methods and just call them from there. For example, I would like to not have to recreate outputPanel in each of the last 4 methods.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int inputMin = 0, inputMax = 0;

    JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextField Min = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField Max = new JTextField(5);
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel("Min: "));
    inputPanel.add(Min);
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel("Max: "));
    inputPanel.add(Max);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    JRadioButton Primes = new JRadioButton("Primes");
    JRadioButton Palindromes = new JRadioButton("Palindromes");
    JRadioButton Emirps = new JRadioButton("Emirps");
    JRadioButton Twins = new JRadioButton("Twin Primes");
    JRadioButton All = new JRadioButton("All");
    buttonPanel.add(Primes);
    buttonPanel.add(Palindromes);
    buttonPanel.add(Emirps);
    buttonPanel.add(Twins);
    buttonPanel.add(All);

    for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, inputPanel,
                "Enter Range 1 - 10000", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        inputMin = Integer.parseInt(Min.getText());
        inputMax = Integer.parseInt(Max.getText());

        if ((inputMin >= 1) && (inputMax <= 10000) && 
                (inputMax > inputMin)) {
            break;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
            (null, "Invalid input. Please try again.", 
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            i++;
        }
    }

    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, buttonPanel,
            "Choose Output", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    if (Primes.isSelected()) {
        primes(inputMin, inputMax);
    } else if (Palindromes.isSelected()) {
        palindromes(inputMin, inputMax);
    } else if (Emirps.isSelected()) {
        emirps(inputMin, inputMax);
    } else if (Twins.isSelected()) {
        twins(inputMin, inputMax);
    } else if (All.isSelected()) {
        primes(inputMin, inputMax);
        palindromes(inputMin, inputMax);
        emirps(inputMin, inputMax);
        twins(inputMin, inputMax);
    }
System.exit(0);
}

public static void primes(int inputMin, int inputMax) {
    JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea outputText = new JTextArea();
    outputText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
    outputText.setLineWrap(true);
    outputText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    JScrollPane thing = new JScrollPane(outputText);
    outputPanel.add(thing);

    int i, j, run;
    boolean prime;
    outputText.setText("The first 50 prime numbers between "
            + inputMin + " and " + inputMax + " are:\n");
    for (i = inputMin, run = 0; i <= inputMax; i++) {
        prime = true;
        if (i == 1) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            outputText.append(i + ", ");
            i++;
        }
        for (j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                prime = false;
            }
        }
        if (prime) {
            outputText.append(i + ", ");
            i++;
            run++;
            if (run == 50) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, outputPanel,
            "Primes", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}

public static void palindromes(int inputMin, int inputMax) {
    JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea outputText = new JTextArea();
    outputText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
    outputText.setLineWrap(true);
    outputText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    JScrollPane thing = new JScrollPane(outputText);
    outputPanel.add(thing);

    int i, j, run;
    boolean prime;
    outputText.setText("The first 20 palindromic prime numbers between "
            + inputMin + " and " + inputMax + " are:\n");
    for (i = inputMin, run = 0; i <= inputMax; i++) {
        prime = true;
        if (i == 1) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            outputText.append(i + ", ");
            i++;
        }
        for (j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                prime = false;
            }
        }
        if (prime) {
            String number = Integer.toString(i);
            int reverse = Integer.parseInt
            (new StringBuffer(number).reverse().toString());
            if (reverse == i) {
                outputText.append(i + ", ");
                i++;
                run++;
                if (run == 20) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, outputPanel,
            "Palindromic Primes", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}

public static void emirps(int inputMin, int inputMax) {
    JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea outputText = new JTextArea();
    outputText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
    outputText.setLineWrap(true);
    outputText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    JScrollPane thing = new JScrollPane(outputText);
    outputPanel.add(thing);

    int i, j, run;
    boolean prime;
    outputText.setText("The first 20 emirps between "
            + inputMin + " and " + inputMax + " are:\n");
    for (i = inputMin, run = 0; i <= inputMax; i++) {
        prime = true;
        for (j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                prime = false;
            }
        }
        if (prime) {
            String number = Integer.toString(i);
            int reverse = Integer.parseInt
            (new StringBuffer(number).reverse().toString());
            for (j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(reverse); j++) {
                if (reverse % j == 0) {
                    prime = false;
                }
            }
            if ((prime) && (i != reverse)
                    && (i < reverse) && (reverse <= inputMax)) {
                outputText.append(i + " and " + reverse + ", ");
                run++;
                if (run == 20) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, outputPanel,
            "Emirps", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}

public static void twins(int inputMin, int inputMax) {
    JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea outputText = new JTextArea();
    outputText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
    outputText.setLineWrap(true);
    outputText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    JScrollPane thing = new JScrollPane(outputText);
    outputPanel.add(thing);

    int i, j, run;
    boolean prime;
    outputText.setText("The first 20 twin primes between "
            + inputMin + " and " + inputMax + " are:\n");
    for (i = inputMin, run = 0; i <= inputMax; i++) {
        prime = true;
        if (i == 1) {
            i++;
        }
        for (j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                prime = false;
            }
        }
        if (prime) {
            int twin = i + 2;
            for (j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(twin); j++) {
                if (twin % j == 0) {
                    prime = false;
                }
            }
            if (prime) {
                outputText.append(i + " and " + twin + ", ");
                run++;
                if (run == 20) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, outputPanel,
            "Twin Primes", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```

}

Comment: 1) get rid of most all static everything in that code. 2) Create real honest to goodness objects with instance fields and methods. If that were my code, honestly, I'd take it out back and shoot it, and start all over but first writing my logic on paper, getting it correct, and then creating objects, non-GUI first, and then GUI, and build my project.

Comment: I possibly should have added that I'm a first semester CS student and very new to Java.

Comment: You asked for improvements, well there you are. Improve. Create objects.

Comment: So why not just create a method, place the code you are using to create the panes in it and return the panel?

Comment: Also, in response to the logic on paper thing: This program already does what I need it to do; there is nothing conceptually wrong with it. I was just looking for help on where to go from where it is, specifically in the direction of using the GUI correctly. The inputs, math, and outputs all work correctly.

Comment: Not if you're going to decompose it into objects. You will need to write your design on paper, trust me.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Because when I return the panel, I don't really know how to make that work with the fact that the panels either require input text, output text, or button selections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You Could

Create a "helper" method that creates the panels in question, for example...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //..
    JPanel inputPanel = createInputPane();
    //...
}

public JPanel createInputPane() {
    JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextField Min = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField Max = new JTextField(5);
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel("Min: "));
    inputPanel.add(Min);
    inputPanel.add(new JLabel("Max: "));
    inputPanel.add(Max);
    return inputPanel;
}
```

The problem with this, is if you need access to the fields contained on the panel, it becomes troublesome...

### You Could

Create a custom panel which provides the basic controls and access functionality required...

```
public class InputPane extends JPanel {

    private final JTextField minField;
    private final JTextField maxField;

    public InputPane() {
        minField = new JTextField(5);
        maxField = new JTextField(5);
        add(new JLabel("Min: "));
        add(minField);
        add(new JLabel("Max: "));
        add(maxField);
    }

    public String getMaxValue() {
        return maxField.getText();
    }

    public String getMinValue() {
        return minField.getText();
    }

    public void setMaxValue(String value) {
        maxField.setText(value);
    }

    public void setMinValue(String value) {
        minField.setText(value);
    }

}
```

Then you can simply create a new instance anytime you need it.

Comment: That's very helpful and gets my mental ball rolling in the right direction. My big problem was the need to access the fields. Thanks!